# Accessing network drive in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, mfc

I a created a network drive on my system and mapped it to Z: drive letter.

Just the explaining the problem I've created a simple program in MFC for accessing MS access 2007 database on Windows7 machine.

Inside 
`CString MyCRecordSet::GetDefaultConnect()` function I have used this as connection string.

```
ODBC;DRIVER={MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)};DSN='';DBQ=Z:\TestFolder\Database1.mdb
```

Everything is working fine If I run the application normally. 
But when running the application as "*Run as Administrator*", I am getting the following error.

[image]

Also if I try to use

> _access("Z:\TestFolder\Database1.mdb", mode)

api , then this api always return -1 for any mode either 00, 02, 04, or 06.

I think it is related with security in windows for accessing network drive, but not getting what exactly the problem is and how to handle such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mapped your Z drive as a non-administrator, you won't see it when running as an administrator.

Try opening an elevated cmd window (i.e. run cmd as administrator), map your Z drive there, and then try running your app again.

**EDIT**

To share a drive from the command line:

```
net use [driveletter]: \\server\share /user:[username] password
```

Comment: First thanks for your reply. Any other alternative without mapping that drive with administrator privilege. What I think is that administrator have highest privilege (Please correct me if I am wrong). 

Currently I don't have the machine from which I can access it. Definitely I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: I've not found an alternative and this has been a pain for me too on Win7 and Win8 - if you map a drive at one user level, you can't see it at others. Maybe the only other thing to try is to disable UAC - but that really defeats the purpose :-(

Comment: can you please share the command for creating network drive using command line.